# Cannot ping past gateway

Tags: networking, ping, gateway

My wifi is connected but I cannot access the Internet irrespective of the network to which I connect. I can ping the gateway but cannot ping 8.8.8.8 (Google's DNS) which shows:

> Destination Net Unreachable.

I tried adding nameserver 8.8.8.8 as the first uncommented line in /etc/resolv.conf but it didn't help. The traceroute 8.8.8.8 shows:

> traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 64 hops max
>
> 1   *  192.168.100.1  45.013ms !N  0.869ms !N

ip link shows the state of enp8s0 as DOWN. I am new to such issues and don't know if this is a problem. I am unable to set it to UP.

Here are some results.

ip link:

> 1: lo:  mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
>
> link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
>
> 2: enp8s0:  mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
>
> link/ether 14:58:d0:0f:f3:d4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
>
> 3: wlp10s0f0:  mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
>
> link/ether b0:10:41:39:3b:5b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
>
> 6: enp0s20u1:  mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
>
> link/ether 52:88:de:07:c0:83 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

ip route:

> default via 192.168.100.1 dev wlp10s0f0 proto dhcp metric 20600
>
> 169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp10s0f0 scope link metric 1000
>
> 192.168.100.0/24 dev wlp10s0f0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.100.122 metric 600

route -n:

> Kernel IP routing table
>
> Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
>
> 0.0.0.0         192.168.100.1   0.0.0.0         UG    20600  0        0 wlp10s0f0
>
> 169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp10s0f0
>
> 192.168.100.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp10s0f0

ifconfig:

> enp0s20u1: flags=4163  mtu 1500
>
> ether 52:88:de:07:c0:83  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
>
> RX packets 3466  bytes 1134955 (1.1 MB)
>
> RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>
> TX packets 2916  bytes 559818 (559.8 KB)
>
> TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
>
> enp8s0: flags=4099  mtu 1500
>
> ether 14:58:d0:0f:f3:d4  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
>
> RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
>
> RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>
> TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
>
> TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
>
> lo: flags=73  mtu 65536
>
> inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
>
> inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10
>
> loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
>
> RX packets 43032  bytes 9435650 (9.4 MB)
>
> RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>
> TX packets 43032  bytes 9435650 (9.4 MB)
>
> TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
>
> wlp10s0f0: flags=4163  mtu 1500
>
> inet 192.168.100.122  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.100.255
>
> inet6 fe80::a8e0:3646:62cd:1204  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20
>
> ether b0:10:41:39:3b:5b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
>
> RX packets 13153  bytes 1546861 (1.5 MB)
>
> RX errors 0  dropped 1  overruns 0  frame 0
>
> TX packets 12343  bytes 1556661 (1.5 MB)
>
> TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

nmcli device:

> DEVICE     TYPE      STATE         CONNECTION
>
> wlp10s0f0  wifi      connected     3rd F_HRB_3
>
> enp0s20u1  ethernet  disconnected  --
>
> enp8s0     ethernet  unavailable   --
>
> lo         loopback  unmanaged     --

ip addr show:

> 1: lo:  mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
>
> link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
>
> inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
>
> valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
>
> inet6 ::1/128 scope host
>
> valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
>
> 2: enp8s0:  mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
>
> link/ether 14:58:d0:0f:f3:d4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
>
> 3: wlp10s0f0:  mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
>
> link/ether b0:10:41:39:3b:5b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
>
> inet 192.168.100.122/24 brd 192.168.100.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp10s0f0
>
> valid_lft 85769sec preferred_lft 85769sec
>
> inet6 fe80::a8e0:3646:62cd:1204/64 scope link noprefixroute
>
> valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
>
> 6: enp0s20u1:  mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
>
> link/ether 52:88:de:07:c0:83 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

ls -l /etc/resolv.conf:

> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Sep 17  2018 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf

/etc/resolv.conf currently has these uncommented lines:

> nameserver 8.8.8.8
>
> nameserver 127.0.0.53
>
> options edns0

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Adding `nameserver 8.8.8.8`  is meant to resolve domain name to ip address, as in `google.com` to `192.168.1.25` for example.  `enp8s0` is the ethernet interface. Your wifi should have `wp*` naming scheme, but for exact name use `ip addr` or `ip link`, and considering you are connected to wireless  it is UP so it shouldn't be a problem. As for the root issue, it may be worth looking at the routing table `ip route` and checking if perhaps your firewall is getting in the way.

Comment: Please include the output of 'ifconfig'

Comment: I believe my colleague @Marmayogi really means: `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks @chili555. It is my mistake. Yes, I wanted `ls -l /etc/resolv.conf` only. I will re-comment it.

Comment: Edit your question and post the output of the following commands: 1. `nmcli device` 2. `ip addr show` and 3. `ls -l /etc/resolv.conf`.